# ROS Path Planning

Tags: python, navigation, ros, robotics

I'm really struggling with ROS and any help will be appreciated, Thank you .
So im trying to use ROS to navigate, the local planner is working perfectly but the global planner paths are not as expected, it's geting so close to the inflated obstacles i will attach a screenshot,
global planner params :
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.33
inflation_radius: 0.13
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxHtK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify correct robot_footprint type and values to create the correct global plan.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).